# How to handle questions about outdated technologies?

Tags: discussion

How do you handle new questions about problems with old technologies.

I tend to cruise mostly through [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) questions, and every once in a while a question will pop up about about [selenium-rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-rc) test not working. [Here is a perfect example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27175898/3124333).
The question is well written, even a quality question, by most SO standards, however, the answer is: That technology has been deprecated several years back, and is no longer being maintained. You will need to upgrade your stuff.

I generally just leave a comment stating such. Is that all there is? Upvoting, even if the question is a quality question, seems not right, but I am not sure. Same goes for downvoting, unless we are talking about honest low-quality question. Closing? But what is the reason?

Does SO have any mechanism where if a user tags a question with certain tag, a pop up will warn them: "Are you sure? This technology is ancient!"

Comment: How about [*60 years* outdated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17bit-and-35bit-integers).  Proper tagging required

Comment: At the [x86] and [assembly] tags, we keep seeing questions about MS-DOS programming everyday.

Comment: So I am talking about questions of magnitude: running .Net 4.0 on Win95 - why doesn't it work?

Comment: @SiKing You answer "You can't, because .NET 4 doesn't work on Win95". Because that *is* the answer. It *still* shouldn't be closed just for being about an outdated tech, or downvoted unless its low quality. "It isn't possible" is an acceptable answer, especially when you can provide sources that show it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Makes sense. So my followup question is: assuming such a question was a quality question as per SO guidelines, is it a good idea to upvote it and thereby give it more visibility on SO?

Comment: @SiKing Absolutely. If it meets all the criteria for upvoting, upvote away. (That particular one would seem like there was no research done, but thats neither here nor there).

Comment: If someone would ask a question on a car forum on how to repair his old-timer, "buy a new car" would not be the answer he/she wants to read...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

People use outdated technology *all the time*. For many reasons, upgrading is not always an option. We shouldn't be "handling" them, we should be answering them!

Since it becomes a bit of an XY problem, feel free to note in your answer (or in a comment) that the tech is deprecated, but if you answer, make sure to **answer the question**.

They certainly should *not* be closed just for asking about old tech (VTC away for other quality issues of course).

Comment: Hell, if we started telling people to always use the latest stuff, we'd basically have to nuke [tag:python-2.7].

Comment: @Kevin Python 2.7 is not deprecated ...

Comment: @Serge: Technically not, but it hasn't received any new features in years and whenever people complain about it, Guido basically *always* tells them to upgrade to 3.x.  The 2.x line [is formally dead](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404).

Comment: There's plenty of people who don't have the luxury of latest and greatest. If a question stands in it's own right - even if something is deprecated - then there's no reason to close it. (The solution might well be 'that's a bug, it's fixed in a new release' though)

Answer (score 5):

For some technologies, deprecated means more than just "no longer supported", it means "no longer available". I'll call them "dead".

This is often the case for "Cloud" technologies, where the vendor has the ability to shut down APIs or entire offerings.

In those cases, it's highly unlikely we'll see many new questions, except for the typical "my code just stopped working!" variety around service shut-down. IMO, those new questions can be dealt with via a comment, then closed. Alternatively, answer the first, then dupe the lemmings.

Old dead tech questions with no answers have no lasting value - close them as off-topic, with a custom "dead tech" reason, for example:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the service it is about has been shut down by the vendor. Any answer is unlikely to be helpful to the general Stack Overflow community.

Old dead tech questions with answers should be considered on a case-by-case basis to determine whether there is lasting value in the answers. I'd consider a question that is focused solely on how to use the dead tech unsalvageable, while questions that are simply using that tech to solve a more general problem may be salvaged with new or updated answers ("XXX is dead, but here's how you'd do that with its replacement...").