# How to handle outdated, unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm planning to start going through the list of unanswered [silverstripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silverstripe) questions and one of the things I noticed when quickly checking through the list was [one specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489379/silverstripe-upload-field-issue-in-mozilla-firefox). It has a specific scenario which not only depends on the version of Silverstripe (in this case, that information is provided) but also the browser version (with several versions of Firefox being released since then). I don't think there is much value for questions like these without upvotes or answers to stay on the site.

I've had a read [of a few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252520/mark-questions-or-answers-as-out-of-date) [other meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280359/how-to-handle-questions-about-outdated-technologies) talking about how to handle outdated questions/answers/technologies though I don't think they really cover this particular situation.

With the amount of time since the question was asked (over 2 years), is it worth still having it on the site? Should I be flagging these questions? (if so, what reason should I pick? Too broad?) Do I just let let bygones be bygones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was never voted on at all, so a single downvote would get it cleaned up soon.

See: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Comment: Ahhhh, that simple! Thanks for the information, bookmarking that link.