# How to handle outdated questions with multiple upvotes and missing OP action?

Tags: discussion, support

Alright my second post on Meta - here is where i expected a answer [How to handle outdated, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281075/how-to-handle-outdated-unanswered-questions) but browsing the unanswered Maven-Questions there are some questions like this [Maven shade and assembly plugins resulting in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442728/maven-shade-and-assembly-plugins-resulting-in-stack-overflow) which seem to not be able to be answered unless the OP decides to answer comment-questions 2 years after he created the question or enoth people to browse the "history" and vote it down ... which obviously did not happen within the last two years... so....

Am i now supposed to vote this down?

Comment: Downvoting a question because you have absolutely no clue what the proper answer might look like isn't a very rational thing to do. If you know it is outdated and no longer a Maven issue then that's of course an answer you could post. If you don't know then you have absolutely no reason to treat it like it is "outdated".  The OP did a pretty poor job of providing repro instructions, ignored the comments too, the probable reason he didn't get an answer.  You can DV for that, it won't make any practical difference.

Comment: @HansPassant Downvoting an answer for not including enough information for the question to be answerable is one of the primary reasons one would ever downvote a question.

Comment: Oh - i thought its programmers here to - nothing to do here for me, good bye funny Meta thing (and thanks everyone contributing here because thats probably the source of the plattforms quality)

Comment: The OP was online just last week, so perhaps a well thought-out comment in his In box may trigger him into reviewing this question. 2 years? I've heard of longer delays in getting an accept.

Comment: You aren't *supposed* to do anything in particular, and maybe the best choice is to do nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question doesn't contain enough information to be answerable, close it for a relevant close reason (unclear, "why isn't this code working", etc.) and downvote it.  This is not at all dependent on the age of the question.