# Penalized for ancient history?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, vote-to-close

I'll preface this with saying I've got nearly 30,000 rep so a few -2's are no biggie, but that said:

I asked this question 9 years ago:

[Something like TryParse for dates/times in c++ (non-Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984295/something-like-tryparse-for-dates-times-in-c-non-windows)

Rules on this site were different (or at least WAY more lax) back then.  I would never ask that kind of question today (I vote to close these all the time myself).

It does seem a little unfair to take 3 downvotes in the same day after no voting on the question for 9 years though, especially since it was (rightly) closed soon after.

Would it be reasonable to have some kind of "it was different back then" rule around rep?  Like, reverse downvotes on old questions if they are received within 24 hours of being closed?  (What's an "old" question?  I dunno - 5 years?)

Or is this just too pedantic and will only help the relatively small number of us who have been here more than those 5 years or so?

Comment: Should that rule also apply to upvotes?

Comment: What would be the benefit for the site of doing something like this?

Comment: I would give it an edit. Instead of *Does anyone know of a library that offers something similar to* edit it to *I'm trying to achieve the same what*. Then you can at least argue it is **not** an off-site resource request. That won't reverse the down votes but at least it addresses why that question attracted that crowd with their close votes...

Comment: Ow we can just delete the question, and the rep you lost should be restored.

Comment: Can we not meta-effect this? There is nothing egregiously wrong with the question that would warrant driving its score down even further.

Comment: @meagar I don't think the entity-with-a-thousand-minds-of-their-own (AKA "meta") is going to listen to you, but given what you say can the question not be improved then?

Comment: Smells like a voting ring at work, no obvious trigger that I see to make them focus on this specific question.  Having a lightning rod for ticked-off SO users to vent their anger is a not a bad strategy btw.  Meta visitors piling on more DVs does suck rather badly.  I voted to delete, you need one more.

Comment: I've casted the final delete vote ... was not needed for the content IMO but Meta, yeah.

Comment: @HansPassant you almost sound disappointed it wasn't SOCVR this time ... ;)

Comment: @Gimby I don’t think any improvement was required, unless OP was determined to have the question reopened.

Comment: Your question has gone through the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20409019), perhaps the votes were by the reviewers?

Comment: @Stijn As one of the close voters I did not downvote.

Comment: @greg-449 I didn't mean to point the finger, sorry. Just wanted to say that this isn't necessarily the work of a voting ring.

Comment: I get hammered on posts from 8+ years ago all the time from people saying "That is not true", well back when it was answered it was true. And no I am not going to try to update my 5k answers so they are up to date. lol

Comment: @epascarello ugh, that's worse than receiving downvotes on ancient content. Feature request: on old content make it so you have to click "yes, I know" three times and "no, I'm sure" two times before you are allowed to post a comment. All nag boxes mention how old the content is.

Comment: @epascarello Why not? Just update it. It's much more useful (and practical) than asking 250 people to downvote your post and upvote the more up-to-date post.

Comment: @user202729 because the question was normally about IE7/8 which is obsolete now and I really do not have time to look over my answers from 9 years ago and update them. If it is a post that someone comments on, I may update it or leave a comment, but I am not going to  put effort in when clearly you can see the question should be archived off, but that really does not exist. JavaScript/CSS answers really do become outdated, not like we have Java version tags for the JS answers.

Comment: Thanks all, no worries.  And yes, I was fully cognizant there might be a meta effect result...

Comment: @epascarello [This meta post disagrees with you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280359/how-to-handle-questions-about-outdated-technologies). ///  A "> Note: Information in this answer is outdated." can be useful.

Comment: @user202729 So yes, people should post a new answer to the question instead of head hunting old answers that were valid. They can clearly update the answer themselves too. It is a double edged sword and people are more happy to down vote than actually do something about it. But there are some answers where it is for a specific browser and people do not realize that back in IE8 crap was not able to do things. The answer still applied to IE8, but people do not read into context and say well it can be done. Yes modern browsers support it. Get 10 years of answers, you will run into this crap. lol

Comment: @epascarello It doesn't hurt to add a simple note "This only applies to IE8" right? ...

Comment: meh, it's just a few rep. At least it got deleted, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to get rid of it on your own.

Answer (score 12):

> Would it be reasonable to have some kind of "it was different back then" rule around rep?

No. People should generally not treat a question differently based on age.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is valid, but I don't think you fully appreciate your timing.
 You're showing an attention bias to the downvotes.

As you said:

> Rules on this site were different (or at least WAY more lax) back
>   then.

I've seen many questions that couldn't possibly be asked today, that have hundreds of upvotes. Should there too be a rule - taking away that reputation? I think not.

Perhaps you're unhappy with the exponential gains you've earned from getting in early? I wouldn't be; it took me 2.5 years of coming here, finding all of my questions already asked, to get to the low-level rep that I have (basic commenting, editing, voting, flagging, and answering extremely limited/non-existent till this last month).

Comment: (a somewhat unrelated note) how come that you got so little rep from edits? At all sites I joined I tried to get my first 200-300 rep points from edits. Granted, it's not too fast (thanks to edit suspension in ancient past I learned not to hurry) but not too slow either, just a matter of several weeks. And it's an invaluable experience because it helps me learn much about subtle ins and outs and how to best use the site

Comment: Edits is finally how I got my answering and voting privileges, yes. It didn't allow me to do any edits in the beginning though. They probably set the time/point prereq according to the community age. I probably gained the privilege last year, but only realized it this year (I badly assumed I would've gotten voting/commenting privileges before editing).